# Database design for storing facebook friends list + Device Addressbook

Tags: c#, php, sql-server, facebook, database-design

How would you design a database to meet the following **two** requirements

Device Addressbook requirements

```
User 1.* Device
Device 1.* Contact
Contact 1.* Email
Contact 1.* Phone
```

Facebook/Twitter Requirements

```
User 1.* SocialNetworkAccount (i.e 1 user can have many facebook accounts)
SocialNetworkAccount 1.* FSocialNetworkAccountFriends (i.e 1 facebook account can have many facebook friends)
```

---

USER is the application user.

Device can be iPhone, ipad, Android, Windows Phone etc

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this. It is a mssql database diagram. But i think you understand it:

[image: Database diagram]

**EDIT**

I don't have any good experience of types tables. These table are hard to query and in most cases a lot a lot of `case when` statements to get the correct data. I would go with the tum rule that one table have one purpose. The problem is also that if you want to add another type then that may requier other column. Then you might find yourself that you have to add nullable columns and that can result in a bad database design.

Comment: Thanks,  I fixed it up , See diagram above, :) email and can be put in the same table , and filter by Contacttype

Answer (score 0):

@Arion

What about this? (ignore device)

[image]